# Linking to external HTML files in jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm creating a project using jQuery Mobile and have been having trouble trying to link separate HTML pages. As of right now, I've got two separate HTML files: pageInitEvent.htm and pageInitEvent2.htm.
I have buttons on both pages and want to link to each other when clicked, I also have an event that gets triggered (or so I want it to be triggered) when the button on the first page (pageInitEvent.htm) is clicked. I have bound this event to the pageInitEvent2.htm using the $(document).on("pageinit", ".pageinit2", function(){ (section of the pageInitEvent.htm file.

My problem is, if I don't include a rel="external" to both buttons they won't work and just give out an error, if I add the rel="external" to both, then they link fine but the event still doesn't get triggered and page transitions if any doesn't work. Is there any way of linking 2 separate html files without compromising the page transitions and making the events work? I have tried this using a multi-page HTML file and it all works perfectly, its just that when I separate them out into different HTML files that everything messes up

**Here is the code for pageInitEvent.htm:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Listing 4.1</title>
    <!-- name attribute tells the browser the meta tag contains information about the viewport or the display size of the page -->
    <!-- content attribute tells browser to display the page with the same dimensions as the device it is beign viewed on -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The jQuery Mobile CSS style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <!-- The standard jQuery library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
            //$.extend allows to merge two objects together
            //$.mobile is the target object to add or merge to
            //The second argument to this function is the settings we want to change or merge to the $.mobile object
            $.extend($.mobile, {
                //change the message that appears when a pageLoadError happens
                pageLoadErrorMessage: 'Either the page cannot be found or it cannot be loaded.'
            });
        }); 

        //binds the pageinitevent with the page pageInit2
        //third argument is an anonymous inner functi
        $(document).on("pageinit", ".pageinit2", function(){
            alert("pageinit is bound!");
        }); 
    </script>

    <!-- The jQuery Mobile library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>pageInit event example</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>The button below will use AJAX to load another page and trigger a bound event</p>
            <a href="pageInitEvent2.htm" data-role="button" >Click to open a new page</a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**The code for pageInitEvent2.htm is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>pageInitEvent2</title>
    <!-- name attribute tells the browser the meta tag contains information about the viewport or the display size of the page -->
    <!-- content attribute tells browser to display the page with the same dimensions as the device it is beign viewed on -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The JQuery Mobile CSS style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <!-- The standard JQuery library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- The jQuery Mobile library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page"  data-url="pageInitEvent2.htm" class="pageinit2">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>pageinit example</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>fantastic!</p>
            <a href="pageInitEvent.htm" data-role="button" rel="external" >Amazing, now take me back</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have managed to figure out the solution to the binding of events. I just now need to know if there is any way of not losing the animated page-transitions? The separate html files are in the same folder, same directory so I don't understand what is going wrong with them, an error keeps popping up when I click the button saying: 'Either the page cannot be found or it cannot be loaded.'

Comment: The links don't seem to work if I just specify the file name i.e. pageInitEvent2.htm. But I think this is perfectly fine as both files are in the same folder and same directory. SO I don't understand what is wrong with this code!!

Comment: If I specify the full location of the file, both buttons work. For the life of me though, I can't understand why just the file name isn't sufficient as they are in the same directory and folder?. Also with this solution, the animated page transitions still aren't working.

Comment: your example works using Firefox, however using Chrome I also get your error _Either the page cannot be found or it cannot be loaded_...

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning unique IDs on each of your divs.

```
<div id="pageA" data-role="page"></div>
<div id="pageB" data-role="page"></div>
```

Comment: I've done that and it doesn't make a difference, but the buttons only seem to work when I put in the full location of the file, not just it's file name. Also when I click on the button the animated page transitions still don't work.